Merge file pdf in subfolder & folder that same 8 last letters name, using pdftk or merge-Pdf
# Define the path to the general folder
$generalFolderPath ='F:\9.POWERSHELL' # - use for my laptop
$outputCsvPath = "F:\9.enter image description herePOWERSHELL" # - use for my laptop


# Create the destination directory if it doesn't exist
$destinationDir = "$generalFolderPath\Merged"
if (!(Test-Path -Path $destinationDir)) {
    New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path $destinationDir
}

# Get all PDF files in the general folder and its subfolders
$pdfFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $generalFolderPath -Recurse -Filter *.pdf

# Group files by their last 12 characters
$groupedFiles = $pdfFiles | Group-Object { $_.Name.Substring($_.Name.Length - 12, 8) }

# Prepare an array to hold merged file information
$mergedFilesInfo = @()

foreach ($group in $groupedFiles) {
    $key = $group.Name 
    $fileList = $group.Group  

    if ($fileList.Count -gt 1) { # check if count of file >=1
        # Generate a temporary list file for PDFtk
        $listFilePath = "$generalFolderPath\filelist_$key.txt" # creat txt file which have full directory of one group file same name
        $fileListContent = $fileList | ForEach-Object { $_.FullName } | Out-String
        Set-Content -Path $listFilePath -Value $fileListContent

        # Define the output file path
        $outputFilePath = "$destinationDir\merged_$key.pdf"
        
        $pdftkPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk\bin\pdftk.exe"
        # Merge the files using PDFtk
        Start-Process -FilePath $pdftkPath -ArgumentList @$listFilePath, "cat", "output", "$outputFilePath" -NoNewWindow -Wait
        
        
        
        
        # Remove the temporary list file
        Remove-Item -Path $listFilePath

        # Add merged file information to the array
        $mergedFileInfo = [PSCustomObject]@{
            MergedFileName = $outputFilePath
        }
        $mergedFilesInfo += $mergedFileInfo
    }
}

# Export the merged file information to a CSV file
$mergedFilesInfo | Export-Csv -Path $outputCsvPath -NoTypeInformation

Write-Host "Merging completed and merged file paths saved to $outputCsvPath"

Please help me this matter:
I need to merge file pdf in subfolder & folder that same 8 last letters name, using pdftk or merge-Pdf; I already tried many times but the combined pdf can't be issued. Please help me what is the problem.
Thanks you so much. I am not good at English so might be mistake grammar
text
I changed my code to get the combined pdf, but no files are issued.
this is the link to view code, this code can make finding same name pdf file, group file list, path of them, but can not make combined pdf file.
https://1drv.ms/u/s!Aqa-XlHkSXykhOc4EUEgdax1YuNyWg?e=GKnDNY

Does "...no files are issued" mean that the $outputFilePath is not created? Do you have a working command line for one (1) invocation of pdftk or merge-Pdf? If there is any error or warning message, please [edit] the question and include the text.

Use $destinationDir = Join-Path -Path $generalFolderPath -ChildPath "Merged". Use the -File switch on Get-ChildItem so that it does not include directories.

I believe there is a typo here Start-Process -FilePath $pdftkPath -ArgumentList @$listFilePath.  Remove the @ in front of @$listFilePath

I thought the command: "Start-Process" was to launch the pdf file merge. So maybe the error is, without pdftk or merge-pdf command will not perform file merging. So I already change the code as below:
$command = "& '$pdftkPath' $pathlist cat output '$outputFilePath'"
Invoke-Expression $command
It run well.

Thanks All for supporting, I already tried to remove the below line,
#(Start-Process -FilePath $pdftkPath -ArgumentList @$listFilePath, "cat", "output", "$outputFilePath" -NoNewWindow -Wait) => remove this line
then replacement by this line:
$command = "& '$pdftkPath' $pathlist cat output '$outputFilePath'" 
Invoke-Expression $command

in which: $pathlist is a string including all directories that need to be merged file.
The merged pdf file is issued.
